# Application of Max Module Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(B(\infty, R))\bigcap C(\partial B(\infty, R))$, and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(z)$ exists. Show that, if $f$ is not constant, then $M(r)=max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$ strictly decreases on $[R, \infty)$.

---

I have tried using Max Module Theorem to prove that $M$ is decreasing on $[R, \infty)$. But I am not sure how to show the "strict" monotonicity.
I am thinking that it may contradict with "$f$ not constant" otherwise, but not aware of how to explain that explicitly.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(z) = f(\frac 1z)$ for $0 < \vert z \vert < \frac 1R$ and
$g(0) := \lim_{z \to \infty } f(z)$. Then $g$ has a 
[removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)
at $z=0$, so that we can apply the maximum modulus theorem to $g$.

It follows that $M(r_1, g) \le M(r_2,g)$ for $0 \le r_1 < r_2 < \frac 1R$, so $r \to M(r, g)$ is increasing, which means that
$r \to M(r, f)$ is decreasing.

If equality holds for some $r_1 < r_2$ then $g$ has a maximum in the interior
of the disc with radius $r_2$, which implies that $g$ (and thus $f$) is constant.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I was stuck just now because of misunderstanding of Max modulus principle. Thanks!