# a small argument about proving holomorphic function as constant

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $|z|>R$, for some large $R>0$. If there exist $r_2>r_1>R$ with $max_{|z|=r_1}|f(z)| = max_{|z|=r_2}|f(z)|$, then $f$ is constant.

NB: $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)<\infty$

---

Previous Note:
That is my argument. I am not sure whether it is true or false.
Also, if necessary, you may add that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)$ exists to consider the argument above.

---

UPDATE: The argument is false for some $f$ with $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$. Now if we add that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)<\infty$, is it true?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't this essentially your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225646/application-of-max-module-theorem?

Comment: Yeah. Previously I wanna solve that one. But I find that it is actually this question.

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample $f(z)=z+1/z$ with $r_1=2$ and $r_2=1/2$.

Comment: Ok, I see. I guess the problem lies in that the limit of $f$ is infinity when $z\to\infty$. If the condition changes to "$\lim_{z→∞}f(z)<\infty$", is it true?

Comment: what does $z\to\infty$ mean when $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: that simply means $|z|\to \infty$.

Comment: okay. So you assume that $\lim f(z_n)$ exists for any sequence with $|z_n|\to\infty$. This implies that all these limits are equal, i.e. there is some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)\to c$ for $|z|\to\infty$. I think the answer to your original question might change to yes in this case, but I can't think of a good proof right now.

Comment: Your understanding is right. We can use Max Modulus Principle to prove that f is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @MartinR for answering my previous question [Application of Max Module Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225646/application-of-max-module-theorem)! I think that it is also OK to write it here directly to prove that $f$ is constant!

### (Weak Version: do not need bounded $D$)

### Max Modulus Principle: Let $f$ be holomorphic in a district $D$. Then if $f$ is not constant, then $|f(z)|$ cannot take maximum in $D$.

Now that $max_{|z|=r_1}|f(z)|=max_{|z|=r_2}|f(z)|$. Then take $D=\{z||z|>r_1\}$. Then there exists some point $w\in \partial B(\infty,r_2)$, so that $|f|$ takes maximum at $w$ in $D$, which may contradict with the principle. So the only possibility is that $f$ is constant in $D$, which implys that $f=const$ everywhere.

I hope this solution is explicit.